# Function doesn't get length of an element in state when the page renders

Tags: reactjs

My input box needs to have the width set dynamically based on the length of its value.

It works when the page is already rendered and if the value is changed.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value={this.state.quantity}
                    onChange={this.quantityChange}
                    onBlur={this.quantityBlur} 
style={this.quantityWidth(this.state.quantity.length)}/>
```

```
quantityWidth(n) {
    const quanityWidth = {
        width: '22px'
    };

    if (n > 1) {
        const initWidth = 22+n*6;
        quanityWidth.width = initWidth+'px';
    }

    return quanityWidth;
}
```

But when the page is rendered with an existing value, it doesn't change the width and the text  gets hidden. What am I missing here?

Comment: When you are saying "with an existing value": do you mean with state.quantity initialized in constructor ? 
If yes, that's weird, everything is working for me

Comment: go through the lifecycle and check what, when renders

Comment: this.state.quantity.toString().length worked!

Answer (score 0):

this.state.quantity.toString().length worked. Didn't realize the data type of the quantity.